# Javascript callback cannot assign value in variable

Tags: javascript

im new in javascript and i want to make random function to display random image for simple scissor rock paper game,
but i have problem when the callback cannot assign value in variable,
anyone have solution?
thanks before

this is my code

```
const arr_option = ['scissors', 'rock', 'paper', 'scissors', 'rock', 'paper'];
function random() {
  const selector = document.getElementsByClassName('img-komputer')[0];

  var i = 0;
  var chooseComp = 'Initial Value';
  const callback = () => {
    var randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr_option.length);
    var comp = arr_option[randIndex];
    selector.src = 'img/' + comp + '.png';
    if (++i === arr_option.length - 1) {
      chooseComp = comp;
      clearInterval(refInt);
    }
  };

  const refInt = setInterval(callback, 250);
  return chooseComp; // this is value not update 
}
```

Comment: What is compChoose?  are u sure that it is compChoose? It may be chooseComp  which you returned

Comment: yeah, that is. but value isn't update with comp value

Comment: your i is always 1 in if condition u never enter in condition. What do u want with if condition ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as first you're returning `compChoose` when you updated `chooseComp`. Btw, js doesn't work in this way, when a value is returned from a method it will not change also if you change into the caller function.

```
function caller() {
    let returnedValue = called();
    // here returnedValue is not updated when it's myVar is updated in called function
}

function called() {
    let myVar = 12;
    setInterval(() => {
        // here you are updating myVar but after a copy of this variable is already returned
        myVar++;
    }, 1000);

    return myVar; // here a copy of myVar is created and returned
}
```

The best option is to use a callback:

```
function caller() {
    // this function inside the parenthesis is the callback
    called(function (updatedValue) {
        console.log(updatedValue);
    });
}

function called(callback) {
    let myVar = 12;
    callback(myVar);
    setInterval(function() {
        myVar++;
        // create a copy of new value of myVar and use it to call the callback
        callback(myVar);
    }, 1000);
}
```

In this way the callback is called every time the `myVar` is updated and send the new value.

Please let me know if it's clear enough.

Answer (score -1):

I can't see where you define compChoose.

Comment: i miss, that i mean chooseComp.. that variable value isn't update with comp value